# Implement gallery-like slider control

Tags: android, android-layout, android-controls

Can't find how to implement such control and don't know even it's name:

[image]

Every 1, 2 and 3 elements are the same custom controls (let name them *items*). Items should be slideable in both directions by finger and (will be great) also by tapping according dots below control.  It is important to see the whole single item at the screen (**not** part of 1st and part of 2nd like with `ListView`).

Is it implementable on Android? If so, please, show how to do this and tell me **the name of this control**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a sample with the same that follows your requirement

[Android - ViewPagerIndicator Demo](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator)

Answer (score 1):

Try: ImageSwitcher,ViewFlipper,ViewSwitcher.

Answer (score 0):

`ViewPager` sounds like what you want: 
http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html

(You'll have to implement the clickable dots yourself, but it should be easy enough, using the `ViewPager`s `setCurrentItem()` method)

Answer (score 0):

use example as given on

http://evgeni-shafran.blogspot.in/2011/08/tutorial-custom-gallery-circular-and.html